# ember-data and json-patch requests

Tags: json, http, ember.js, ember-data, json-patch

Can ember-data send json-patch PATCH on model.save() call?
(with media type application/json-patch+json RFC6902)

The documentation says yes but with no details:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_persisting-records

Testing it shows PUT requests with the entire model in the request.

Comment: Not by default. But you could write an adapter and serializer pair that does this.

Comment: I would have to clone that for every model?

Comment: Not at all. The application adapter and serializer will be used if you dont have another adapter/serializer for a model. So put it in your application adapter/serializer.

Comment: Ok, this kind of adapter maybe available somewhere, isn't dit? I can't believe this job has to be written by framework user.

Comment: There was a [RFC for adding JSON Patch support to Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/5) but the decision was to leave this for user space. Not sure if there is a well established addon. [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/), GraphQL and some custom REST APIs are far more used in Ember community than JSON Patch.

Comment: Json:api doesn't countersays json patch, isn't it? Damn, custom rest API more used than well established standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your application uses the `RESTAdapter` and not the `JSONAPIAdapter`.

[RESTAdapter](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/RESTAdapter) was the default adapter before Ember Data 2.0 as stated [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.22.0/models/customizing-adapters/)

You can take a look a both adapters `updateRecord` methods:

[RestAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/adapter/addon/rest.js#L742-L765)

```js
/**
    Called by the store when an existing record is saved
    via the `save` method on a model record instance.
    The `updateRecord` method serializes the record and makes an Ajax (HTTP PUT) request
    to a URL computed by `buildURL`.
    See `serialize` for information on how to customize the serialized form
    of a record.
    @method updateRecord
    @param {Store} store
    @param {Model} type
    @param {Snapshot} snapshot
    @return {Promise} promise
  */
  updateRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    const data = serializeIntoHash(store, type, snapshot, {});

    let id = snapshot.id;
    let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'updateRecord');

    return this.ajax(url, 'PUT', { data });
  }
```

[JSONAPIAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/adapter/addon/json-api.js#L234-L240)

```js
updateRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    const data = serializeIntoHash(store, type, snapshot);

    let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, snapshot.id, snapshot, 'updateRecord');

    return this.ajax(url, 'PATCH', { data: data });
  }
```

As you can see, one uses `PUT`, the other `PATCH`. The JSONAPIAdapter is now the default one, that's why the documentation deals with `PATCH` requests.

If you want to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT` and keep `RestAdapter`, you should extend from `RestAdapter` and modify the `updateRecord` method :D

I hope it will find you well ;)